# can i add a scroll to striped table (boostrap) in html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use a striped table (boostrap) but with a scroll. In my code, i just call the class table-striped and the tables looks fine. Now i need to add a scroll to that same table keeping the same style. Is that posible? how?

Here is some of my code

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
 <div class="col-sm-7">
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
<tr>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Year</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escor</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2001</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
   </div>        
   </div>
  </div>
```

I don't know where to find the css code. I used a boostrap template.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I also added the table and table-hoover classes. So i need to keep all three styles i mentioned.

Comment: Please edit and add in your code with some comments

Answer (score 0):

Set a height and overflow-y: scroll in your style

```
table {
    height: 30px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

when data loading and the space are not enough for data, table will show a scroll.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header stays put, no scrolling</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="display: block; border: 1px solid green; height: 30px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1/1</td>
            <td>cell 1/2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 2/1</td>
            <td>cell 2/2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 3/1</td>
            <td>cell 3/2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: copy the following and past in the <tbody> tag

Comment: style="height: 30px; overflow-y: scroll"
change the height as you want